# Shapefile empty after export of Add XY Data using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, export

I am using ArcMap.

I have a sheet with 3111 records. Using "add xy data" its attribute table is fine but when I exported it as .shp file it only displays header.

How do I solve this problem?

[image: exported image]

Comment: When you say "a sheet", do you mean an Excel spreadsheet?  If so, ArcMap does a fairly poor job of handling these.  Before you do ANYTHING with a spreadsheet in ArcMap, I always export it to a table (in a file geodatabase), and then do what ever is required to the table instead of to the spreadsheet.  So add XY data to the exported table, etc.  You can convert Excel to table using the tool in the "Conversion" toolbox.  If you are not talking about an Excel spreadsheet, then please consider editing your question to say "table" or "feature class" instead of "sheet".

Comment: Problem solved, it was due to multiple points in the same location.